# How to implement delegate in QHeaderView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7

I have created one table by using QTableview and QAbstractTableModel . i have added some vertical header by using QHeaderView . In one of the header cell i want to use delegate ..

I am using the delegate but it does not have any impact ..

Is anywhere i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this issue myself. The answer from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qheaderview.html) is simple and annoying:

> Note: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does
>   not rely on a delegate. As a result, calling a header's
>   setItemDelegate() function will have no effect.

In other words you cannot use delegates with QHeaderView.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if you want to style a QHeaderView section, you'll have to do it either via the header data model (changing Qt::FontRole, etc.) or derive your own QHeaderView (don't forget to pass it to your table with "setVerticalHeader()") and overwrite the its paintSection()-function.
i.e.:

```
void YourCustomHeaderView::paintSection(QPainter* in_p_painter, const QRect& in_rect, int in_section) const
{
    if (nullptr == in_p_painter)
        return;

    // Paint default sections
    in_p_painter->save();
    QHeaderView::paintSection(in_p_painter, in_rect, in_section);
    in_p_painter->restore();

    // Paint your custom section content OVER a specific, finished
    // default section (identified by index in this case)
    if (m_your_custom_section_index == in_section)
    {
        QPen pen = in_p_painter->pen();
        pen.setWidthF(5.5);
        pen.setColor(QColor(m_separator_color));

        in_p_painter->setPen(pen);
        in_p_painter->drawLine(in_rect.right(), in_rect.top(), in_rect.right(), in_rect.bottom());
    }
}
```

This simplified example could of course easily be done via a stylesheet instead, but you could theoretically draw whatever you like using this method.

Comment: You might want to include an example of the derived class. Please take note that this question is quite possibly for Qt-4.x considering its age.