# In a QTableView, how can I make horizontal header cells display vertical text?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5

I wish to make horizontal header cells in a QTableView display text from top to bottom (i.e., vertically), how can I do this?

Example PyQt5 app which displays a QTableView with a horizontal header showing text in the normal direction:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return

        return 'Header Data'

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return

        return 'Row Data'

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        main_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(main_widget)

        view = QTableView(main_widget)
        view.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        model = TableModel(view)
        view.setModel(model)
        view.resizeColumnsToContents()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple [use of delegate will not work here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896835/1387438).

You need to subclass [QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#details) and override [paintSection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#paintSection).
In implementation of it you need:

- rotate and translate painter
- calculate new rectange which wil take into acount above transformation
- call old implementation of `paintSection` with new values
- restore painter state (reverse transformation).

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to insert newlines between each character in the text of header cells (see the model's headerData method):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return

        # Make text appear flowing downwards
        return '\n'.join([x for x in 'Header Data']).replace(' ', '')

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return

        return 'Row Data'

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        main_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(main_widget)

        view = QTableView(main_widget)
        view.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        model = TableModel(view)
        view.setModel(model)
        view.resizeColumnsToContents()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```