# QItemDelegate: rotate text 90 degrees

Tags: qt, rotation, qitemdelegate

I have a span of cells (1 column, 5 rows) where I would like display text on a 90 degree angle.  I know I'll need to resize the geometry, but for now I can't even get the text to show up.  In the middle row, I'm doing this within my subclassed QItemDelegate::paint()

```
QString data = "String";
painter->rotate( 90 );
painter->drawText( opt.rect, Qt::AlignLeft, data );
```

Basically I get nothing printed in this case.  A few other questions lead me to code like this.  Am I missing something?

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22634541/1387438

Comment: That looks like it's for the QHeaderView.  I need to rotate text in the actual view - in the cells.  I assumed I could do this in a reimplemented paint().

Answer (score 0):

Pattern is same as in link I posted in comment. This should look like more or less like this. I could messed up some sign or do some typo.

```
#include "customitemdelegate.h"
#include <QPainter>

CustomItemDelegate::CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void CustomItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem newOption(option);
    QTransform transform(QTransform::fromTranslate(-option.rect.center().x(),
                                                   -option.rect.center().y()));
    transform.rotate(90);
    painter->setTransform(transform);
    transform=transform.inverted();
    newOption.rect=transform.mapRect(newOption.rect);
    QItemDelegate::paint(painter, newOption, index);

    // restore state of painter
    painter->setTransform(transform);
}

QSize CustomItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index).transposed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Still getting a blank though.  Might be worth noting I've subclassed QStyledItemDelegate, although I wouldn't think that would make a difference.  Will mess around a bit.

Comment: The update contains exact contents of cpp file I used to verify this solution. It works perfectly. `QTransform::fromTranslate` part can be removed and still it works.

Comment: Ok "perfectly" is to strong word. There is a problem with cells borders and this can't be simply fixed.

Comment: take a pick inside Qt code, it can be quite easily fixed: https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/ea2befbe538b031972adc76b926f1e6b95b689de/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qitemdelegate.cpp#L655

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference.  The only discrepency I see (and I apologize as it's an error in the original post) is that I'm inheriting QStyledItemDelegate, not QItemDelegate.  I wouldn't think that would make a difference here though.

Comment: I will try this code with a vanilla QItemDelegate and a simplier model/view, etc.  The one I'm using now is one I've subclassed and heavily modified.